# Check constraint to allow only one combination of two columns

Tags: sql-server, data-modeling, check-constraint

I have a table to store person's phone numbers. There is a flag (IsDefault) to mark a phone as the default one. There should be only one phone per person flagged as default phone.
Is it possible to create a check constraint to only allow one combination of  PersonId and IsDefault = True?

Comment: Check constraint? No. You're wanting to assert something about *multiple* rows (some people attempt to do this using UDFs but they often mis edge cases). Indexed view or filtered index, Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a filtered index, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PhoneNumber (
ID int primary key,
PhoneNumber nvarchar(20),
PersonID int,
IsDefault bit
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_Default_PhoneNumber
ON PhoneNumber(PersonID)
WHERE IsDefault = 1
GO
```

This enforces a unique PersonID only where IsDefault is true.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I needed! :-)